# How to exclude songs or playlists from iTunes Songs?

Tags: itunes

I have audiobooks, voice memos, among other things that have a place in my library, but don't need to be in my music list.

Is there anyway to exclude them or hide them from Music?  It's annoying to hit 'play' and be bombarded with pieces of books instead of actual music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're in the music-section of iTunes, only "music" should be played.
Make sure your audiobooks and memos are categorized as such by doing a right-click on them and selecting info.
Then, in the "options" tab, there's a dropdown where you can select a kind (music, audiobook, etc.)

(if the dropdown is grey [as in: not selectable], turn off iTunes Match, change it, and turn it back on)

Answer (score 1):

In the Settings of the Song/Track u can set the Option to Skip/Don't play on continous Playback (Sry don't know the exact Name of the Setting in English my OS X is in German)

Comment: Thanks, this works for shuffling, but not in general